# É possivel utilizar operadores lógicos dentro do "cout"? - C++

Tags: c++

Gostaria de saber se tem como utilizar operadores lógicos e/ou operador ternário dentro do cout, assim como é possível dentro do printf.

---

```
int main ()
{
   int n = 5;

   //Como fazer isso (Funciona)
   printf ("O numero %se maior que 5\n", n > 5?"":"nao ");

   //Utilizando cout (Nao funciona)
   cout << n > 5?"O numero e maior que 5":"O numero nao e maior que 5" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O que acontece é que os operadores  `>>` e `<<` que são "shift right" e "shift left" são redefinidos para o objeto "cout" e funcionam para "canalizar" os objetos que você quer colocar na saída padrão.

Só que redefinir um operador (override) não muda sua prioridade - ou seja, uma vez que `<<` tem mais prioridade que o `>`,  ele vai ser executado antes - e daí pra frente vai tudo dar errado.

Pra resolver, simplesmente coloque parenteses em torno da expressão toda que deseja jogar para o cout:

```
cout << (n > 5?"O numero e maior que 5":"O numero nao e maior que 5") << endl;
```

Agora, todo a expressão entre parênteses é resolvida, e o seu resultado é que é usado com o `<<`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!